# toFixed function not working properly ( please give a reason not an alternative)

Tags: javascript, math

`toFixed()` function responding differently for float values.
For Example:

```
 var a = 2.555;
 var b = 5.555;

console.log(a.toFixed(2));  /* output is 2.56 */ 
console.log(b.toFixed(2));  /* output is 5.55 */
```

For 2.555/3.555 results are (2.56/3.56)

and

For other values(not sure for all values) it is showing #.55 (# refers to any number)

I am confused can any one help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [toFixed javascript function giving strange results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105787/tofixed-javascript-function-giving-strange-results)

Comment: This is not a duplicate one, in the link above the answer that is approved is an alternative of toFixed() function I don't want alternative I want t know the exact reason why toFixed()  function is working like this. @NoDownvotesPlz

Comment: Please check this url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768083/tofixed2-rounds-x-525-inconsistently. It helps you hopefully.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Javascript uses a binary floating point representation for numbers (IEEE754). This format is able to represent exactly (without approximation) only numbers that can be expressed in the form n/2<sup>m</sup> where both `n` and `m` are integers.

Any number that is not a rational where the denominator is an integral power of two cannot be represented exactly because in binary it is a periodic number (it has infinite binary digits after the point).

The number `0.5` (i.e. 1/2) is fine, (in binary is just `0.1₂`) but for example `0.55` (i.e. 11/20) cannot be represented exactly (in binary it's `0.100011001100110011₂…` i.e. `0.10(0011)₂` with the last part `0011₂` repeating infinite times).

If you need to do any computation in which the result depends on exact decimal numbers you need to use an exact decimal representation. A simple solution if the number of decimals is fixed (e.g. 3) is to keep all values as integers by multiplying them by 1000...

```
2.555 --> 2555
5.555 --> 5555
3.7   --> 3700
```

and adjusting your computation when doing multiplications and divisions accordingly (e.g. after multiplying two numbers you need to divide the result by 1000).

The IEEE754 double-precision format is accurate with integers up to 9,007,199,254,740,992 and this is often enough for prices/values (where the rounding is most often an issue).

Answer (score 3):

Try this [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/L0xfdrgn/)

```
function roundToTwo(num) {    
    alert(+(Math.round(num + "e+2")  + "e-2"));
}

roundToTwo(2.555);
roundToTwo(5.555);
```

Comment: Yes this is working fine, thanks for the reply, but I am not looking for any alternative. I want to know why this ( toFixed() ) function is responding like this.

Comment: check this may be u ill be clear http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp

Comment: @IshanDemon take it from here instead http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: if youre are agree means please accept my answer :) @IshanDemon

Comment: Not quit satisfactory, although your function is a good alternative of toFixed()

Comment: check this may be u can understand bit clearly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493745/tofixed-simple-use-explanation-in-text-field

Answer (score 0):

toFixed() method depending on Browser rounds down  or retain.

Here is the solution for this problem, check for "5" at the end

```
 var num = 5.555;
 var temp = num.toString();
if(temp .charAt(temp .length-1)==="5"){
temp = temp .slice(0,temp .length-1) + '6';
}
num = Number(temp);
Final = num.toFixed(2);
```

Or reusable function would be like

```
function toFixedCustom(num,upto){

     var temp = num.toString();
    if(temp .charAt(temp .length-1)==="5"){
    temp = temp .slice(0,temp .length-1) + '6';
    }
    num = Number(temp);
    Final = num.toFixed(upto);
    return Final;
}

var a = 2.555;
 var b = 5.555;

console.log(toFixedCustom(a,2));  
console.log(toFixedCustom(b,2));
```